# Batch Script File Output and Input

Tags: file, batch-file, input, output, last-modified

I want to get the last modified date of every file in a directory in windows, output that to a text file, and then read each line of that text file as input.

Below are the contents of my .bat file.

```
@echo off
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE "PATH='\\Users\\n63206\\Desktop\\Project\\'" GET Name, LastModified > out.txt
for /f %%a in (out.txt) do (
echo %%a
)
echo test
```

After I run the script, only "test" gets printed out. When I open out.txt, I see the last modified dates that I output to it displayed fine, and if I create a new text file (cannot use out.txt) and manually enter some lines in there, my for loop can print out all the lines in that file. Any advice to help me figure out the issue here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the generated file is a UTF-16, little endian, BOM prefixed file. That is, it contains two bytes per character and is prefixed by two characters, 0xFF 0xFE.

`for /f` is not able to read this file.

Your options are:

1 - Read the information as it is generated

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    ' wmic datafile where "path='\\Users\\n63206\\Desktop\\Project\\'" get name^,lastmodified '
) do echo %%a
```

2 - Once the file is generated, convert the file while reading it

```
wmic datafile where "path='\\Users\\n63206\\Desktop\\Project\\'" get name,lastmodified > out.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type out.txt') do echo %%a
```

3 - Convert the file while generating it

```
wmic datafile where "path='\\Users\\n63206\\Desktop\\Project\\'" get name,lastmodified | find /v "" > out.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (out.txt) do echo %%a
```